# Any java based frameworks/tools to handle pattern matching and pattern filling

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

**Edit**

Apparently people aren't actually reading this question. I realize I can do pattern matching with regex. Which is what my example code does, the main problem is the pattern filling and handling that nicely without having to split the regex up in to it's individual tokens and figuring out what the number is supposed to look like. I can write that without any issues. I was just looking to see if someone else had already solved this problem in a more elegant way.

---

I'm working on a project that needs to take in a string and check to see if it matches a pattern, and also be able to take that pattern and fill out the value if needed. I can hack this together using regex and forcing specific regex formats, but I was curious if there was a preexisting framework/library that can do this.

My needs a pretty simple, so I don't need it to be able handle any possible string. Just something basic formats like this:

```
String pattern "\\d\\d\\d\\d";
String testString = "123";
testString.matches(pattern); // False
String filledOutString = fillOutStringFromPattern(testString);
filledOutString.equals("0123"); // True
```

One caveat is that it might not always be numeric only, so it's not quite as simple as just transforming it in to a number then printing the number with padding.

Right now my plan is to simply force people to put in the regex pattern using only `\d\d\d` instead of `\d{3}` and then just do some very simple splitting up of the regex, but before I went about doing that wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way of doing this.

Comment: You should be able to use Java's regex capabilities. Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) tool.

Comment: @Avantol13 is on the money with this one. Java already has many built in Regex classes. A quick Google search should provide you with some answers, or even looking at the "Related" section to the right of this comment.

Comment: Yes as I said in my original question, I realize that I can use regex for matching, which is what my example code does. But the pattern filling isn't quite as simple, and regex doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/)** to generate/fill strings based on patterns.

Here an interesting example from its documentation:

```
String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```

For your case, you could use:

```
String regex = "\\d{4}";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```